# OneDrive for Business : Search Item using Microsoft graph client always return exception "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException"

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

As it is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_search?view=odsp-graph-online), using the Microsoft Graph REST API you can Search the hierarchy of items for items matching a query.

This works fine, as expected when we using API based approach using postman : https://{xxxxxx}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/me/drive/root/search(q='Test')

Same functionality when we want to use Microsoft graph client, and it produces error.

Eg :

`await graphClient.Me.Drive.Search(searchText).Request().GetAsync();`

Error :

Code: -1, 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException
Message: Cannot find resource for the request microsoft.graph.search.

Note : Same graphClient search call works properly for OneDrive for personal but not work for oneDrive for Business.

Comment: Hi @Anand did you find anything useful ?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you want to search the `DriveItems` using MS Graph.

Based on your posted, you get the `DriveItems` in the root. However, you get the drive when you use the MS Graph.

We can use the follow code to get the DriveItems in the root.

`await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Request().GetAsync();`

However, refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search-parameter), the search query parameter is only support the message and person collections. So you can't use here.

Comment: I already tried with, 


`await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Search(searchText).Request().GetAsync();`



Still getting the same error as mentioned in question.

Comment: You can try remove the Search method, and check whether it work

Comment: Without search it works fine. But I required search functionality over here so search is required. Same will works fine when I had done integration with "OneDrive for Personal" but this will not works for "OneDrive for Business"

Comment: my apologizes.I have modify my answer. If this is helpful, please mark me as answer